# Getting an infinite calling stack with this javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, infinite-loop

I have:

```
var c = {
    typeStart: function(msg, loc) {
        loc.append("<p>");
        this.typeLetter(msg, loc, 0);
    },

    typeLetter: function(msg, loc, pos) {
        loc.append(msg.charAt(pos));
        pos = pos + 1;
        if (pos == msg.length) { this.typeEnd(loc); }
        setTimeout(this.typeLetter(msg, loc, pos), 100);
    },

    typeEnd: function(loc) {
        loc.append("</p>");
    }
}

c.typeStart("hello", $("#somediv"));
```

For some reason, and I'm obviously missing something, `typeLetter` is being called infinitely. I assume its something to do with javascript's asynchronous nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
typeLetter: function(msg, loc, pos) {
    loc.append(msg.charAt(pos));
    pos = pos + 1;
    if (pos == msg.length) { this.typeEnd(loc); }
    setTimeout(this.typeLetter(msg, loc, pos), 100);
},             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This function will be called and the *result* will be passed into `setTimeout`. You need to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.typeLetter(msg, loc, pos);
}, 100);
```